# Google App Engine standard - composer update --lock | Allowed memory size exhausted | Error 255

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

we have a PHP - Symfony project that we would like to run on Google Cloud App Engine Standard but we cannot deploy the app using `gcloud app deploy app.yml` because the build fails.

app.yml

```
runtime: php
service: "papi-dev"
instance_class: F2
env_variables:
  APP_ENV: prod
  APP_DEBUG: true
  DATABASE_URL: mysql://p...
runtime_config:
  document_root: ./public
  front_controller_file: index.php
  enable_stackdriver_integration: true
handlers:
# Declare the build and bundles directory as static assets to be served by the
# App Engine CDN.
- url: /build
  static_dir: public/build
```

composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "7.2.*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "api-platform/api-pack": "^1.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^5.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "^1.6",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "google/cloud-error-reporting": "^0.12.1",
        "google/cloud-logging": "^1.14",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.4",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.5",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^1.5",
        "pear/net_dns2": "^1.4",
        "productsupcom/jenkins-php-api": "^0.1.4",
        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "^7.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/lock": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "*",
        "symfony/templating": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "*",
        "webonyx/graphql-php": "^0.12.6",
        "wisembly/elephant.io": "^3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "4.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

builder log

```
Step #1 - "builder": INFO composer_update_lock composer update --lock
Step #1 - "builder": INFO `composer_update_lock` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9437184 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php on line 565
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
Step #1 - "builder": INFO `composer_update_lock` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder": Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Step #1 - "builder": Loading composer repositories with package information
Step #1 - "builder": Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Step #1 - "builder": Package operations: 128 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Step #1 - "builder": - Installing symfony/flex (v1.1.8): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%) Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR error: `composer_update_lock` returned code: 255
```

The deploy command used to work until we've added more packages to composer.json. Best guess I have so far is that the build stopped working because of this github commit to the [cloud builder image](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/runtimes-common/pull/724) which executes `composer update --lock` upon every deploy/build execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Google - composer install is called instead of composer update.

Comment: Yeh, that kind of defeats the purpose of composer update though

Comment: @Cameron Composer update is something that you should only execute in a dev environment and willingly, not that 3rd party build system updates your project's dependencies without you even knowing about it.

Comment: It does not. Imagine that you make deploy to production and dependencies change in the background and something breaks. This is the main purpose of using a package manager in the first place - list dependencies and lock their versions especially for PROD environments.